# How to Simplify Nested Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
blocks.map((item) => {
    return item.SubCategory.map((subItem) => {
      return subItem.modal.map((modal) => {
        let Blocks = selectedBlock === item.Category;
        let SubBlocks = selectedSubBlock === subItem.id;

        if (SubBlocks && Blocks) {
          return bm.add(modal.id, {
            label: modal.label,
            content: modal.content,
          });
        }

        return null;
      });
    });
  });
```

How Can we Access modal Array Without Nesting it any Possibilities Like Using Lodash Object Methods to Access the Required Key get(val, 'val.val.val') is there any Option to do Like this in Array Methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let modals = ["modal1", "modal2", "modal3"];
let subitems = [modals, modals, modals];
let items = [subitems, subitems, subitems];
let blocks = [items, items, items];

let modals_only = blocks.flat(3);
console.log(modals_only) // Array(81) [ "modal1", "modal2", "modal3", ... ]
```

In your scenario, I would write

```js
blocks.flat(3).map(block => {
    //...
});
```